# MongoDB find() query

Tags: mongodb

here's data sample,

```
{
    "posts" : [
        { "title": "A",
        "num": 1 },
        { "title": "B",
        "num": 1 },
        { "title": "C",
        "num": 2 }
    ]
}
```

I want to get results that "num" = 1 by

```
db.example.find( { posts: { num: { $eq: 1 } } } )
```

But it doesn't work.
What's the problem?

Comment: You are querying on the `role` property but this property does not exist in your data sample...

Comment: Sorry, that's not a problem... I updated

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work. Do you not get any results? Do you get an error? Also I noticed you do not pass a callback function to your `find` method. Is this intentional?

Comment: I cannot get any results. And I run this code on mongodb console, so there's no callback function.

Comment: Do you want to get the whole document or just the objects with num = 1?

Comment: The latter. I want to get objects with num = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.example.find({ posts: { $elemMatch: { num: 1 } } } )
```

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks.